# CFG myapp.exe.cfg file for QT

Tags: c++, qt, exe

I want to use a CFG file to config link to a DLL for my app using QT Creator. Example Garena have file `garena.exe.cfg`. It links DLLs to path `./cef/`:

```
"<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <dependency>
    <file name="Qt5Core.dll" path="Qt5Core.dll" />
    <file name="Qt5Gui.dll" path="Qt5Gui.dll" />
    <file name="d3dcompiler_43.dll" path="cef\d3dcompiler_43.dll" />
    <file name="d3dcompiler_47.dll" path="cef\d3dcompiler_47.dll" />
    <file name="libcef.dll" path="cef\libcef.dll" />
    <file name="libEGL.dll" path="cef\libEGL.dll" />
    <file name="libGLESv2.dll" path="cef\libGLESv2.dll" />
    <file name="widevinecdmadapter.dll" path="cef\widevinecdmadapter.dll" />
    <file name="widevinecdmadapter.dll" path="cef\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll" />
  </dependency>
</configuration>"
```

How to create CFG file with QT?